# How to initialize a string array in a main Java method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, program-entry-point

I have written some code which creates and initializes a String ArrayList. Is it possible to declare the arguments directly in to the String [] args method itself, rather than creating an extra String arrayList?

```
public class sampleCode{
    public static void main(String[] args ) {

    String[]args2 = {"en", "es"};

        if( args2[0].equals("en")) {
            System.out.println("english option");
        }
        else if( args2[1].equals("es")) {
            System.out.println("spanish option");
        }
        else System.out.println("this is the default option");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. I don't see any ArrayList in your code above. Also what do you mean by 'Is it possible to declare the arguments directly in to the String [] args method itself'? What's your intent?

Comment: My arrayList was the "en" and "es". The args2 object they they are saved in is simillar to the "String[] args " main method above. I wish to make this code more concise and print "English option" when en is first array and "spanish option" when es is second option.

Comment: ??? Please re-state that, since that does not make logical sense.

Comment: You are confusing terms suggesting that you may be Java tutorial deficient. For your own good and ours, please check them out -- you can find the tutorials here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, It was difficult to understand your request, but I get it finally.

The answer of your request is YES. Yes it is possible to not create an extra array of String in your code. In this case, you need to enter the options `en` and `es` using the command line.

Here is how to update your code:

```
public class SampleCode { 

  public static void main(String[] args ) {

  //String[]args2 = {"en", "es"};

  if( args[0].equals("en")) {
    System.out.println("english option");
 }
 else if( args[1].equals("es")) {
    System.out.println("spanish option");
 }
 else { System.out.println("this is the default option");}

 }
}
```

Now, here is the process:

1. In your `terminal`, compile your code : `javac SampleCode.java`
2. And execute it by giving the arguments: `java SampleCode "en" "es"`

It is a possible manner to do what you need. But in this case, **english option** will always be obtained.

Hope, it helps you.